# Volume of comma-like teardrop shape or a 3d paisley shape

Tags: calculus, geometry, integration, pi, volume

[image]

Whats the formula for the volume of a comma-like teardrop shape or 3d paisley shape? In other words, how to revolve a curve around another curve? Take any arbitrary case you like to show just the mathematical form. 
I have not found it online yet.

Comment: Do you know calculus?  And, how "curvy" is the teardrop?

Comment: Solid of a revolution.  See: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/VolumeWithRings.aspx http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SolidofRevolution.html

Comment: With an integral.  Calculating the volume of the shape you describe requires knowledge of integral calculus.  Furthermore, you need to specify exactly what kind of shape you have--there are infinitely many curves that would "look like" a teardrop, but they would each have a different volume formula.

Comment: @anorton Would you please quote any arbitrary example? So that i get a push to start.

Comment: See my answer below for a simple example.

Comment: @anorton, the axis of *your* teardrop is a straight line.  I think the OP wants a paisley design such as this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0f/MaangaDesign.JPG/220px-MaangaDesign.JPG, where the "axis" is *not* straight.

Comment: Ah ha.  Ok.  Well...  I'll think about that for a while.

Comment: Oh, That was quite simple the lower part is a half sphere and the rest is a curved cone. The height of cone is the average of smaller curve and bigger curve.